# ¿Como reemplazar y rellenar en un archivo usando otro como guia en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Vengo yo nuevamente, necesito ayuda en el momento de reemplazar texto.

Tengo dos archivos uno donde se va a añadir el texto y otro con el texto que se añade;

```
# TODO: Translation updated at 2021-07-11 19:13

# game/emails.rpy:11
translate Spanish emails_78046b0c:

    # mt "No reply yet about Amy's pictures. I should check back tomorrow."
    mt ""

# game/emails.rpy:42
translate Spanish date_required_36a6e5e6:

    # mt "Great, I have an email back from the escort agency. Let's see what they said."
    mt ""

# game/emails.rpy:45
translate Spanish date_required_a411a2b6:

    # mt "Holy crap. That's a lot of money!"
    mt ""

# game/emails.rpy:46
translate Spanish date_required_1929020a:

    # mt "Let's take a look at her picture at least though."
    mt ""
```

Y este es el texto que se añade:

```
Aun no hay respuesta sobre las fotos de Amy. Deberia volver manana.
Genial, tengo un correo electronico de la agencia de acompanantes. 
Santo cielo. Eso es mucho dinero!
Sin embargo, echemos un vistazo a su foto al menos.
```

Lo que necesito es por cada comillas doble que este vacía se reemplace su espacio vació y se rellene con su contra parte del numero de la linea del otro archivo, que en otras palabras quede así;

```
# TODO: Translation updated at 2021-07-11 19:13

# game/emails.rpy:11
translate Spanish emails_78046b0c:

    # mt "No reply yet about Amy's pictures. I should check back tomorrow."
    mt "Aun no hay respuesta sobre las fotos de Amy. Deberia volver manana."

# game/emails.rpy:42
translate Spanish date_required_36a6e5e6:

    # mt "Great, I have an email back from the escort agency. Let's see what they said."
    mt "Genial, tengo un correo electronico de la agencia de acompanantes."

# game/emails.rpy:45
translate Spanish date_required_a411a2b6:

    # mt "Holy crap. That's a lot of money!"
    mt "Santo cielo. Eso es mucho dinero!"
```

(No puse todo para que no sea mas largo el post, pero sirve para dar la idea)
Estuve probando unas cosas, pero la que mas me acerco al resultado fue esto:

```
elif number == 3:
    archive = str(input("\n(*) File to replace data(with the extension): "))
    translation = str(input("\n(*) File to extract translation(with the extension): "))

    a = open(archive, 'r+')
    b = open(translation, 'r')

    atext = a.readlines()
    btext = b.readlines()

    find = ' ""'
    num = 0

    for line in fileinput.input(archive):
        if find in line:
            a.write(line.replace(find, btext[num]))
            num += 1

    a.close()
    b.close()
```

pero a la hora de ejecutarlo me da como resultado esto:

```
# TODO: Translation updated at 2021-07-11 19:13

# game/emails.rpy:11
translate Spanish emails_78046b0c:

    # mt "No reply yet about Amy's pictures. I should check back tomorrow."
    mt ""

# game/emails.rpy:42
translate Spanish date_required_36a6e5e6:

    # mt "Great, I have an email back from the escort agency. Let's see what they said."
    mt ""

# game/emails.rpy:45
translate Spanish date_required_a411a2b6:

    # mt "Holy crap. That's a lot of money!"
    mt ""

# game/emails.rpy:46
translate Spanish date_required_1929020a:

    # mt "Let's take a look at her picture at least though."
    mt ""    mtAun no hay respuesta sobre las fotos de Amy. Deberia volver manana.

    mtGenial, tengo un correo electronico de la agencia de acompanantes. Veamos lo que dijeron.

    mtSanto cielo. Eso es mucho dinero!

    mtSin embargo, echemos un vistazo a su foto al menos.
```

Osea que pone todas las palabras al final.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución:

```
with open("original.txt", "rt") as original:
    with open("reemplazo.txt", "rt") as reemplazo:
        with open("traduccion.txt", "wt") as traduccion:
            for linea in original:
                if 'mt ""' in linea:
                    linea = linea.replace('mt ""', f'mt "{reemplazo.readline().rstrip()}"').rstrip()
                traduccion.write(linea)
```

El proceso es abrir ambos archivos de entrada (texto original y reemplazos) y luego recorrer las líneas del archivo original, grabando las líneas originales/traducidas en el archivo `traduccion.txt`.

En cada línea buscar la cadena `mt ""`. Si se encuentra, realizar el reemplazo. Para generar el texto de reemplazo usamos f-string:

```
f'mt "{reemplazo.readline().rstrip()}"'
```

Obtenemos el texto de reemplazo correspondiente simplemente leyendo la siguiente línea en el archivo de reemplazos, ya que ambos archivos van siendo leídos en forma sincronizada.

Tenemos que aplicar `rstrip()` a cada línea leída para descartar el `\n` al final. Si lo dejamos, aparecerán saltos de línea extras en la salida.

**Demo**

El resultad producido en el archivo "traduccion.txt" es

```
# TODO: Translation updated at 2021-07-11 19:13

# game/emails.rpy:11
translate Spanish emails_78046b0c:

    # mt "No reply yet about Amy's pictures. I should check back tomorrow."
    mt "Aun no hay respuesta sobre las fotos de Amy. Deberia volver manana."
# game/emails.rpy:42
translate Spanish date_required_36a6e5e6:

    # mt "Great, I have an email back from the escort agency. Let's see what
 they said."
    mt "Genial, tengo un correo electronico de la agencia de acompanantes."
# game/emails.rpy:45
translate Spanish date_required_a411a2b6:

    # mt "Holy crap. That's a lot of money!"
    mt "Santo cielo. Eso es mucho dinero!"
# game/emails.rpy:46
translate Spanish date_required_1929020a:

    # mt "Let's take a look at her picture at least though."
    mt "Sin embargo, echemos un vistazo a su foto al menos."
```

#### Solución con expresiones regulares

Un método más seguro de reconocer las líneas donde efectuar los reemplazos es usar expresiones regulares. En este caso, nos interesa reconocer líneas donde sólo aparezca (en cualquier parte de la línea):

```
mt ""
```

Si tiene cualquier otra cosa, simplemente la grabamos sin reemplazar.

La expresión regular que reconoce esto es `r'^\s*mt ""\s*$'`, que se lee:

- `^` parear al comienzo de la línea.
- `\s*` cero o más *white spaces*.
- `mt ""` exactamente este texto.
- `\s*` cero o más *white spaces*.
- `$` fin de la línea.

Primero generamos un patrón que reconoce está expresión regular:

```
patron = re.compile(r'^\s*mt ""\s*$')
```

y luego lo aplicamos en cada línea. En lugar del original:

```
if 'mt ""' in linea:
```

escribimos:

```
if patron.search(linea):
```

El método `search` retorna un objeto `re.Match` si la línea cumple con el patrón, o `None` si no lo encuentra. En este caso no nos interesa el resultado exacto de lo encontrado, solo detectar el patrón.

**Código**

La versión completa con expresiones regulares:

```
import re

patron = re.compile(r'^\s*mt ""\s*$')
with open("original.txt", "rt") as original:
    with open("reemplazo.txt", "rt") as reemplazo:
        with open("traduccion.txt", "wt") as traduccion:
            for linea in original:
                if patron.search(linea):
                    linea = linea.replace('mt ""', f'mt "{reemplazo.readline().rstrip()}"').rstrip()
                traduccion.write(linea)
```

Comment: Vale vale pero tengo una duda, qué se puede hacer si no solo esta "mt" en el archivo, ya que este es la abreviación de una persona entonces hay mas personas por ejemplo "jt".

Comment: Oh, ya lo solucioné, muchas gracias la verdad.